# Method for saving any text within speech marks from one file to another file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, xargs

I have a large dataset text file that I would like to extract certain strings from using Unix/Linux. For instance, a line in the dataset looks like this:

```
"Hacked.html","hacked1.txt","Restore.html","Test.url","Hacking.txt"
```

I'd like to extract any strings/file names within the "" and save to another empty file with a list of the text, output like this:

```
Hacked.html
Hacked1.html
Restore.html
Test.url
Hacking.txt
```

However, my language knowledge of Linux (Bash etc) is limited. Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, its highly encouraged for original posters of question.

Answer (score 0):

Hop this Help File1 is the sources, File2 in destination.
I think you will have some lines with comma that you need to delete after

`grep -oP '\"\K[^"]+' file.txt > file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F',' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print substr($i, 2, length($i) - 2)}}' src > dst
```

Notes:

- we assume `src` is your input and `dst` is the destination file;
- `-F` sets the input field separator, in our case `,` character;
- `NF` holds the total number of fields in the input record;
- `$0` is the whole input record - that's why we start with `$1` - the first field;
- we call `substr()` command to ignore the first and the last characters of each field.

Comment: This script seemed to do the trick, thanks for your help. Your explanation of it was also very useful.

Comment: @EarthlyBale11 You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle